# Doubt in Moment equation

Tags: moment-generating-functions

**Hi, my doubt is, How $ \mu_1(z) = 0$ in the below text?**

[image: Moment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just expand out the definition (2.6-46) with $n=1$ and use the facts that
$\sum_k p(z_k) = 1$ and $\sum_k z_k p(z_k) = m$.

Comment: K k.. let me do